# Cast unsigned char* array into a jObject

Tags: c++, java-native-interface

I don't have much experience in C++. I'd like to know is it possible to convert `System::Collections::Generic::List<cli::array<unsigned char>^>^` into a `jObject.`
My requirement is to pass a jObject to Java from JNI native code. 
If this impossible, is there any workaround?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It isn't possible to *cast,* as per your title, but you can *convert* it, by wrapping it in Java byte array, via `NewByteArray()`, and populating it with `SetByteArrayRegion().`

Comment: can you give a snippet. I'm bit confused.

Comment: The snippet would be trivial. I suggest you have a look at the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/functions.html#wp17314).